# Trying to create zip folder and download all the files but code is't working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-ziparchive

I am trying to download all files in zip folder on button click but my code isn't working. here following is my code

getting data into database 
put files in array
i already have zip folder named "office_specs.zip"
but something is wrong

```
  public function downloadSpecs(){

        $officeSpecs = DB::table('specifications_draged_files')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        $files = array();

        foreach($officeSpecs as $officeSpec){
           $files[]  = 'http://abc.def.biz/uploads/zeda_specs/'.Auth::user()->id.'/files/'.$officeSpec->draged_file;
        }
        $zipname = 'http://abc.def.biz/uploads/zeda_specs/office_specs.zip';

        $zip = new \ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($zipname, \ZipArchive::CREATE);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file);
        }
        $zip->close();

        header('Content-Type: application/zip');
        header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
        readfile($zipname);

    }
```

Following is the error i am facing

```
This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://abc.def.biz/download-specs might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
```

Comment: anything in apache or PHP log file?

Comment: Are you trying download files and put those files in a zip? If you are trying to get files from another site, you need first download the files and before zip it. If the files are from your site, you need to put the correct filepath for it

Comment: i am getting files in an array and then zip the files in array in zip folder and dowload all the files i am reading is from my own website